# Android RecyclerView setVisibility not working properly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, imageview

I have RecyclerView which contains user bookmarks. The plan is bookmarked item will be marked with certain icon. This is my code in onBindViewHolder():

```
// ...
if (bookmarks != null) {
    for (BookmarkModel bookmarkData : bookmarks) {
        if (bookmarkData.getLetterId() == letter && bookmarkData.getEntryId() == entry) {
            holder.imgBookmark.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.imgBookmark.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

However, the RecyclerView is not showing all bookmark icons, only a few of them. Currently I have 3 bookmarks yet it only shows 1 of them. I have debug it and verified that holder.imgBookmark.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) have been called 3 times. How to update the image properly?

Comment: I suggest you to add the full code of the adapter instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to put break when the letter and entry match. Because of it, only the last match would show the icon.

```
if (bookmarks != null) {
    for (BookmarkModel bookmarkData : bookmarks) {
        if (bookmarkData.getLetterId() == letter && bookmarkData.getEntryId() == entry) {
            holder.imgBookmark.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        } else {
            holder.imgBookmark.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```